# Can someone blocked on XBox Live still join your world in Minecraft?

Tags: xbox-network, minecraft-legacy-console

If you block someone on Xbox live, can they still join your Minecraft world? Just wondering, I haven't had anyone I need to block yet, although there are a few I'm considering x3

Comment: If they could, it would be a pretty bad blocking feature. So I would assume they can't.

Answer (score 2):

No, they cannot. Blocking means they cannot join a world you are hosting, their messages will not be shown, and they will see that you have blocked them.